# Can't open HPROF file with Eclipse Memory Analyzer

Tags: java, heap-memory, stack-dump

[Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools#Java) prompts me only with this message: "Invalid [HPROF](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/HPROF.html) file header".

Stack dump:

```
    java.io.IOException: Invalid HPROF file header.
    at org.eclipse.mat.hprof.AbstractParser.readVersion(AbstractParser.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.mat.hprof.Pass1Parser.read(Pass1Parser.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.mat.hprof.HprofIndexBuilder.fill(HprofIndexBuilder.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.mat.parser.internal.SnapshotFactoryImpl.parse(SnapshotFactoryImpl.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.mat.parser.internal.SnapshotFactoryImpl.openSnapshot(SnapshotFactoryImpl.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.mat.snapshot.SnapshotFactory.openSnapshot(SnapshotFactory.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.mat.snapshot.SnapshotFactory.openSnapshot(SnapshotFactory.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.mat.ui.snapshot.ParseHeapDumpJob.run(ParseHeapDumpJob.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

The HPROF file was made on a Linux machine.

[HAT](https://hat.dev.java.net/) doesn't work and the [IBM HeapAnalyzer](http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/heapanalyzer) is to complicated, but did work.

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: Was the dump made with an incompatible JVM? If jhat doesn't work I'd assume there was something wrong with the dump.

Comment: Heapdump format problem?  Binary vs text.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue.  Adding the flag "format=b" fixed the issue.  Apparently, Memory Analyzer can only read binary files.

Comment: AM having the same issue, where did u add "format=b"?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a java service wrapper, most likely the JVM got killed before it could finish writing the heap dump.  You may want to set a property for the service wrapper that will give the vm more time to complete the heap dump.